# Solving for $x$ in $3^{2x+1} = 3^x + 24$

Tags: logarithms

I'm having trouble solving this equation step by step:

$$3^{2x+1} = 3^x + 24$$

I've tried to take the log of both sides but then I am stuck with the right hand side being $\log(3^x + 24)$. I've found the answer to '$x$' by trial and error but cannot arrive at the answer otherwise.

Can anyone please show how to work it out properly?

Comment: Hint: assume $3^x=t$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $u = 3^x$, then we have:

$$ 3u^2 = u + 24 $$
$$ 3u^2 - u - 24 = 0$$

Which is a quadratic in $u$. Solve, and then use that $u = 3^x$ in order to find $x$.

Comment: Thanks but how do you get the '3' in the 3u^2 from the original 3^(2x+1)?

Comment: @GezBishop $3^{2x+1} = 3^{2x}\cdot3= 3\cdot(3^x)^2$

Comment: Thanks very much everyone!

Answer (score 4):

You can write $3^{2x+1}-3^x=24$ and factor to get $3^x(3^{x+1}-1)=2^3\cdot 3$.  The first factor on the left is the only one that can have a factor $3$, so $x=1$

Comment: That assumes looking for integers solutions...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:   That is correct.  They are often easier to find, and so I often start there.  Here it works.